# Undefined Index Error - Wordpress Functions

Tags: php, wordpress

Receiving a few errors when trying to edit my custom posts in the admin area.

Notice: Undefined index: phone in functions.php on line 146

Undefined index: phone in functions.php on line 130

```
function landing_details(){ 
global $post; 
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID); 
$phone = $custom["phone"][0]; 
?> 
<p><label style="width: 100px; display: inline-block;">Phone Number:</label> <input         name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" size="50"/></p>
<?php }
}
```

Line 130 being `$phone = $custom["phone"][0];`

```
//Add post saving
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');
function save_details(){
global $post;
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){   
    return $post_id;  
}else{ 
update_post_meta($post['ID'], "phone", $_POST["phone"]);

}
}
```

Line 146 being `update_post_meta($post['ID'], "phone", $_POST["phone"]);`

Any help would be much appreciated. Im very new to this and this alone has taken me forever to figure out!

**RESOLVED**  at least no more errors returning!

```
function landing_details(){ 
global $post; 
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID); 
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) return
$phone = $custom["phone"][0]; 
?> 
<p><label style="width: 100px; display: inline-block;">Phone Number:</label> <input   name="phone" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['phone'])) { echo ($_POST['phone']); } ?>"  size="50"/></p>
<?php }
}
```

Next Block

```
//Add post saving
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');
function save_details(){
global $post;
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){   
    return $post_id;  
 }else{ 
if (!empty($phone))

 update_post_meta($post['ID'], "phone", $_POST["phone"]);

}
}
```

If this was not the correct approach please let me know as i am trying to learn best practices!!! thanks!

**New Issue**

Now the value isnt showing in the text box if the custom post has a value entered.....

Comment: Has `$_POST['phone']` been set? ie, what is returned by `isset($_POST['phone'])`? Same thing with the `$custom` array.

Comment: note ive tried to use `if(isset);` but im unclear on how to properly implement. Read elsewhere that is the fix but cant seem to figure it out for the life of me

Comment: You don't want to read `$_POST['phone']` without checking if it's set first. `isset()` returns a boolean.

Comment: Ok that makes some sense. so would this be on the right track? `if(isset($_POST['phone'])){
  return;
 }else{
   update_post_meta($post['ID'], "phone", $_POST["phone"]);`

Comment: i fixed line 146 using `if(!empty($phone)) update_post_meta($post['ID'], "phone", $_POST["phone"]); `                however that same approach doesnt work for me on line 130

Comment: Also, thanks Mike for hinting me into the right direction, if i indeed did this correctly

Comment: welp, no errors showing in admin, but i am having the problem of the phone not showing if a value has been put in for that post

Comment: Here is a clear example of it. Try to do some thing like this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591671/wordpress-meta-box-confusion

Comment: Here is a clear example of it. Try to do some thing like [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591671/wordpress-meta-box-confusion