# wordpress meta-box confusion

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My question is on `save($postID)` function. Here there is a parameter `$postID` which is using in the function for saving as id. I see that this `$postID` has a null value. How does actual post id work for `$postID`?

```
This is the simple meta-box code

/* simple meta box */

/* creating field */

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_post_options_box');

function my_post_options_box() {
    if ( function_exists('add_meta_box') ) { 

        add_meta_box('post_header', 'Asif, save me!', 'testfield', 'post', 'normal', 'low');
    }
}


function testfield(){
global $post;
?>
<input type="text" name="Asif" id="Asif" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Sumon', true); ?>">
<?php
}

/* end of creating field */

/* storing  field after pressing save button */
add_action('save_post', 'save');
function save($postID){


    if (!defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && !DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $postID;
    }
    else
    {       
        if($parent_id = wp_is_post_revision($postID))
        {
        $postID = $parent_id;
        }

        if ($_POST['Asif']) 
        {
            update_custom_meta($postID, $_POST['Asif'], 'Sumon');
        }

    }

  }



 // saving in postmeta table
  function update_custom_meta($postID, $newvalue, $field_name){
    if(!get_post_meta($postID, $field_name)){
 // create field
    add_post_meta($postID, $field_name, $newvalue);
     }
   else{
//update field
     update_post_meta($postID, $field_name, $newvalue);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where have you placed this function . ?

Comment: The above code is placed inside function.php in my wordpress theme. the code is working correctly. But I am not understanding how the parameter of save function is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used the wrong Action Hook.

Instead of using `add_action('admin_menu', 'my_post_options_box');`

Use `add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_post_options_box');`

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_post_options_box');

function my_post_options_box() {
    if ( function_exists('add_meta_box') ) { 

        add_meta_box('post_header', 'Asif, save me!', 'testfield', 'post', 'normal', 'low');
    }
}
```

You can look in to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box for detailed overview.

Some SO Question/Answers you can look into.

- [Add multiple dates to custom post type in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302980/add-multiple-dates-to-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/24315059#24315059)
- [how to add a meta box to wordpress pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890617/how-to-add-a-meta-box-to-wordpress-pages)

### While Saving Post

Action `save_post` automatically passes Post ID to callback function. Which you can use inside your callback function.

Some already answered quesitons

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41912/perform-an-action-when-post-is-updated-published

**Reference**

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post